# manipulate a result set from laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've just picked up laravel after deciding to move to a php framework. I'm retrieving a result set of articles from a database using an eloquent query:

```
$posts = Article::select(array('articles.id','articles.article_date','articles.image_link','articles.headline','articles.category', 'articles.published'));
```

this works fine and results come out as expected.

However I now want to change the format of the article date from the mysql date format to another for the entire collection.

I thought about iterating through the object and changing using the usual php methods but wondered if there was an easier way to manipulate the data either when initiating the query or en mass with the object itself.

I've looked at mutators? but wasnt sure if this was appropriate or how to implement

Any help, pointers appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, mutators are the way to go. (Laravel 3 syntax)

[Getter and Setter documentation for Eloquent models](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#getter-and-setter-methods)

```
public function get_article_date()
{
    return date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($this->get_attribute('article_date'));
}
```

Getting the attribute

```
$articles = Articles::get(array(
    'article_date', 
    'image_link', 
    'headline', 
    'published'
));

foreach($articles as $article)
{
    echo $article->article_date;
}
```

Every time you get the date from your model it will run through the mutator first returning your modified result.

Absolutely no need to run raw queries for something like this.

**EDIT** got set and get mixed up... more coffee needed (answer edited)

Comment: crikey - two solutions! thank you - i'll give this one a go as well and post back

Comment: Not 100% sure how tom implement this solution at the moment. I placed this code in my article model but so far doesn't appear to have altered the date format as expected - is that correct? how does it get called?

Comment: I guessed (rightly or wrongly) you were using Laravel 4 from your query. Can you confirm this? If L3 the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: Hi - laravel 3 at the moment....being a complete newbie to laravel should I switch to 4 now whilst learning???

Comment: No not at all stick with 3 at the moment. 4 is still in beta :) will change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is working, but give it a try

```
$posts = Article::select(array('articles.id',DB::raw('CAST(articles.article_date as date)'),'articles.image_link','articles.headline','articles.category', 'articles.published'));
```

Comment: great - this was almost there for the result required - I wasnt sure about raw but changing your answer to this:    $posts = Article::select(array('articles.id',DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(article_date, "%d/%m/%Y") AS uk_date'),'articles.image_link','articles.headline','articles.category', 'articles.published'));    provided the date in the correct format. Thanks